# Unable to set cookie in CEF

Tags: c++, frameworks, chromium-embedded

Using cef's SetCookie method I wish to set the cookie in such a way that with every request made by cef to the browser the cookie for that request url is set and sent with the request.When I set the cookie I get true however when I log the request headers I am unable to see the cookie I have set.Using SetHeaderByName method this can be achieved but I wish to use SetCookie.I want to know which is the best cef callback function to call the SetCookie method in and how to validate correctly if the cookie is set without using VistAllCookie and VisitUrlCookie

```
CefRefPtr<CefCookieManager> manager = CefCookieManager::GetGlobalManager(nullptr);
CefCookie cookie;
CefString(&cookie.name).FromString("name");
CefString(&cookie.value).FromString("value");
LOG(WARNING)<<"------is cookie set "<<manager->SetCookie(CefString(url),cookie,nullptr);
```

Right now I'm setting the cookie after creation of browser window.
The url I run my application on : http://localhost:9000/#https://www.google.com.
If I'm missing on some parameters while creating the cookie could someone provide me with right dummy parameters to use.

Answer (score 0):

To verify if a cookie was set, pass a callback to the setCookie(3rd argument).

Create a subclass of CefSetCookieCallback

```
class MyCookieCallback: public CefSetCookieCallback {  
   void OnComplete(bool success) {
      //success will tell if you cookie was set or not. 
   } 
}
```

Also try adding cookie.path as well.